# Reference secret value from a configmap

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to reference a secret value from a configmap?

Example:

**CONFIGMAP: app.properties**

```
context-path=/test-app1
dbhost=www.db123.com
username=user1
password=[getValueFromSecret]
```

the value of password here is saved in k8s secret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in core, but you can use the configmapsecrets operator for this. https://github.com/machinezone/configmapsecrets

Helm also has accessors to do it client side.